# Implement Amazon API. Proper way to include files?

Tags: api, amazon

I'm working on a Magento extension and I need to implement Amazon Merchant fullfillment API(`https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/doc/merchantfulfillment/merchantfulfillment/v20150601/php.html/275-1952245-7686132`).
And since I'm new in developing extensions(mostly edited existing ones), I'm wondering what is the best way to do this.
Do I just place the files in a separate folder(in the Model dir f.e?) folder and then use `require_once` to call the ones I need or there's another approach?

I'm sorry if my question is somehow incomplete or unclear. Will do my best to clarify something if needed.

Comment: Ummm... based on your question, you've got quite a task ahead of you; essentially, if you had the minimum level of experience to do this integration, you wouldn't need to ask this question at all. Do you understand autoloading? Is this for Magento 1 or Magento 2? What is the scope of your integration?

Comment: Libraries like the one downloaded from that page should be placed in the `lib` directory

Comment: Yes, managed to get the whole thing to work after I saw @benmarks response and started actually reading about what he said.